# What rhetorical techniques are these?

Tags: rhetoric

1. "This is what you can do"
2. "This is what Americans can do"

To me, these two sentences seem different because (1) feels like it is directed at individuals, singling someone out. But (2) feels like more general, directed at a whole group of people. What rhetorical techniques are these and do these two sentences use different techniques?

Comment: Your examples are identical. You can replace **you** and **Americans** by any noun phrase and the structure remains the same. The second point is that without context, neither appear to be rhetorical/rhetoric. You have given no context and therefore I am inclined to vote to close.

Comment: As Greybeard says, we need a context - the sentence(s) immediately before or immediately after (or even both.  'This' is being used in a sentence like this as a 'signpost'.  It may refer BACK to a longer statement of what we can do, and in that case acts as a sort of grand finale.   Or it may refer FORWARDS to what is coming next.  "You wonder what we can do? THIS is what we can do.  We can [A]; we can [B] ...."  Which is it in your case?

Comment: @Tuffy It refers forwards. It is followed by some imperative statements. "Speak up." "Teach others."

Comment: Grammatically, one could describe *This is what you can do* as being in the second person and *This is what Americans can do* as being in third. As a rhetorical device, one could describe *This is what you can do* as a form of “direct address.” *This is what Americans can do* would then be called — for lack of a better term — “indirect address.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd say "This is what you can do" defaults to instruction, perhaps even hectoring (hortatory or injunctive modality):

- *"It would be really helpful if you ..."*
- *"Come on, let's make a start." ...*
- *"Get a move on!"*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can) (adjusted) picks up on these usages:

> **can** used to request [/require] something:
>
> - *If you see Brett, can you tell him I'm in town next weekend?*
> - *Can you make a little less noise, please? I'm trying to work.*
>
> ...
>
> **can** [informal] sometimes used to tell someone angrily to do something:
>
> - *If you carry on being horrible to your sister, Sophie, you can just go to bed!*

But it *can* also be used in the alethic (stating what is possible) sense:

- *"You're certainly **not** useless. Don't be so down on yourself. This is [a list of] what you can/are able to do."*

...............

And I'd agree that "This is what Americans can do" defaults a lot more to the alethic interpretation, far less 'in your face', as the second person address is absent.

"This is what you Americans can do" takes us back to the hortatory default.

But as usual, these expressions are ambiguous, open to different interpretations, as we usually find to be the case with the mysterious modal verbs.

Context will almost always disambiguate, so the question lacks necessary detail for definitive interpretations.

Comment: Good analysis. Can we also say second person vs. third person?

Comment: ................Yes.